# Ruby on Rails: How to use scope named 'open'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I use Rails 3.2.8 in my project and I want to use scope named 'open'

`scope :open, where(:closed => false)`

in order to send it with JSON. Something like `json.open @foo.bar.open.count`. But Rails recognizes `.open` as Ruby method (related to open files, I guess), not as my scope (and throws error "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)")
. How can I force Rails to use my scope, not Ruby method?

Comment: Can you not just name it something slightly different?

Comment: is `@foo.bar` a class or an object ? It has to be a class.

Comment: @oldergod I think your original answer was correct. I was about to upvote it when you deleted it. I was going to answer the same thing.

Comment: @airat-shigapov `open` is not a reserved method name on the `ActiveRecord::Base` *class*, so this shouldn't be a problem. i.e. `MyClass.open` should work fine if you define `open` as a scope on `MyClass`, and `MyClass` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: @shioyama I was in a rush and was not sure it would fit the OP's question. I undeleted it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 3, `scope` and `class method` are basically the same thing.

I think you are calling the `instance method` instead of the `class method`.

```
class Foo
  scope :open, where(:closed => false)

  def open
    #instance_method
  end
end
# how to call them
Foo.open # scope/class method
Foo.new.open # instance_method
```

Answer (score 1):

`open` is not a reserved method name on the `ActiveRecord::Base` *class*, so this shouldn't be a problem.

E.g.:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :open, :where(:closed => false)
  ...
end

Post.open
#=> [#<Post id: 1, closed: false>, #<Post id: 5, closed: false>, ... ]
```

(@oldergod posted something similar and deleted his answer.)